# Can't start Jar auto-executable file in CentOS

Tags: java, jar, centos

I have a executable JAR file (https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/releases/download/v7.4.0/jhipster-registry-7.4.0.jar). I want to start it on a centOs server.

If I use commande below it's OK (also on windows terminal !)

```
java -jar ./jhipster-registry-7.4.0.jar start
```

But, in my project architecture, we use to start jar file directly with command :

```
./jhipster-registry-7.4.0.jar start
```

All our previous installation works like with but for this new, I have this message :

```
-bash: ./jhipster-registry-7.4.0: cannot execute binary file
```

I think there is specific parameters but I don't know them. Do you known what is wrong ?

Thank for your help

An example of sucessful execution

[image]

And bad execution :

[image]

File command
[image]

Comment: Normally, for an executable jar: `java -jar jhipster-registry-7.4.0.jar`

Comment: Sure, it's that I say, but on my application, previous teams have made that jar can be executed directly by its filename ...

Comment: I've never seen that nor do I know how that would work. *If* it could you'd probably have to do `chmod +x jhipster-registry-7.4.0.jar; ./jhipster-registry-7.4.0.jar`

Comment: Yet I have a JAR from another old registry that runs this way. I think the previous team recompiled it but I don't know what was done in it.

Comment: I'm sceptical ;) Essentially you would be 'executing' a zip file. How does that work?

Comment: I think that anywhere there is the java command (java -jar with options). In the project maven build (with plugin) ? In a environnement variable (I haven't see anything) ...

Comment: The only files that execute *at the command line* that are not ELF executables are scripts. And they only execute if and when they have a shebang. Desktop 'launchers' are a different thing

Comment: Please do `file (whatever-the-path-is-to)/registry/V6.0.2/registry.jar`

Comment: Effectivily, jar are not the same (see capture).

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems resolved, in my project, we use spring-boot-maven-plugin

We have to add this configuration for make JAR executable :

```
<executable>true</executable>
```

Jar is now "data file" and not "zip file" and we can execute it